# Removing the wrong rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with coordinates which I transformed in SpatialPoints and noticed some would fall in the Pacific and some in the Atlantic ocean.

So I looked at the coordinates at Google Maps and did this to remove those in the Atlantic

```
data_arvore<- data_arvore[which(data_arvore$longitude < -34.8),]
```

And then, to find out which points were in the Pacific:

```
data_arvore[which(data_arvore$latitude < 7 & data_arvore$longitude < -82),]
```

I needed this 2 conditions, because if I used only the first, it would exclude everything in Brazil, and If I used only the second, it would exclude some points in Mexico. I got this print:

```
3007  GB19507     5.550000 -87.03000

4085    GB943     0.000000 -99.00000

4086    GB942     0.000000 -99.00000

4087    GB940     0.000000 -99.00000

6672   GB4718     0.000000 -99.00000

7282   GB5497     0.000000 -99.00000

7283   GB5496     0.000000 -99.00000

10354 GB12229     0.000000 -99.00000
```

The first number is the Row number, the second is my code, followed by latitude and longitude. I have to exclude the last 7 rows (because the two first are not in the ocean, but in a small island):

```
data_arvore2<- data_arvore[which(data_arvore$latitude != 0 & data_arvore$longitude != -99),]
```

But this code removed points which the latitude was 0 and the longitude was not -99, and also points which the longitude was -99 and the latitude was not 0. New attempt:

```
data_arvore2 <- data_arvore[-c(4085,4086,4087,6672,7282,7283,10354), ]
```

The new object, data_arvore2 has 7 rows less than data_arvore... But the points were still falling in the ocean... I noticed that the code removed the wrong rows. Then I started again, but removing the rows in the Pacific before removing the points in Atlantic, and it worked. I figured out that in the first attempt I was removing the 4086th row, which was not the row number 4086. Changing the order of the operations gave me the desired result, but I would like to know how to deal with that situation and remove the right rows... Can you give me a tip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a OR instead of a AND:

```
data_arvore2<- data_arvore[which(data_arvore$latitude != 0 | data_arvore$longitude != -99),]
```

You can also do this :

```
data_arvore2<- data_arvore[which(!(data_arvore$latitude == 0 & data_arvore$longitude == -99)),]
```

Or this (in R you can use negative indices to exclude some terms)

```
data_arvore2<- data_arvore[-which(data_arvore$latitude == 0 & data_arvore$longitude == -99),]
```

In your second attempt you confused row names with row numbers, they were the same when you wreated an initial table, but after subsetting and reordering they're not anymore.

I think something like this would have worked :

```
data_arvore2 <- data_arvore[-match(as.character(c(4085,4086,4087,6672,7282,7283,10354)),row.names(data_arvore), ]
```

Comment: Happy to help :)!

Comment: By the way I Just noticed now because I answered a bit fast, but you don't need the which in the 3 first solutions,  it works fine to give an array of booleans instead of indices

Answer (score 1):

This is a script that utilizes the `maptools` package. You can provide it with your original `data_arvore` dataframe and it should remove any locations that fall over oceans.

```
library(maptools)

# Load the wrld_simpl polygon
data(wrld_simpl)

# Map the locations from data_arvore
pts <- SpatialPoints(data_arvore[,c("longitude","latitude")], proj4string=CRS(proj4string(wrld_simpl)))

# Find which points fall on oceans
data_arvore$ocean <- is.na(over(pts, wrld_simpl)$FIPS)

# Not necessary, but will generate a map showing locations
plot(wrld_simpl)
points(pts, col = 3 - data_arvore$ocean, pch=16)

# Remove locations that fall on oceans
data_arvore <- data_arvore[data_arvore$ocean == FALSE, ]
```

Comment: Hi, Matt... Thank you for your help... I got very excited with this possibility... It would help me a lot... but it didn¹t work... I get the following... > pts <- SpatialPoints(data_arvore[,c("latitude","longitude")], proj4string=CRS(proj4string(wrld_simpl))) Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string’ for signature ‘"character"’ ...

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was good for general use, however the global map in the `maptools` package does not have the level of detail required to capture points that fall on small islands. The code below can be used to obtain maps from gadm.org which have a higher level of detail.

The maps used have are much larger in size, and so it is recommended to only include maps for countries that are within your dataset. In this example I am including country maps for Costa Rica, Nicaragua, and Panama.

First run this script in order to download and combine the country maps you need into a single file.

```
library(rgdal)
library(prevR)

#### Download and combine map shapefiles for required countries ####
#### This section only needs to be run one time in order to create a single map file with all countries needed ####
#### These map files will be downloaded from http://www.gadm.org/ ####

  # Create vector of countries to obtain maps for. Use only the three letter country abbreviation
  # Country code abbreviations are available at this website http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/country_code_list.htm
  countries <- c("CRI","NIC","PAN")

  # Create a temporary working folder
  tempfldr <- tempdir()

  # Set paths for temporary folders for zip files, unzipped maps, and final map
  map.zips <- file.path(tempfldr, "mapzips")
  maps.fldr <- file.path(tempfldr, "maps")
  final.fldr <- file.path(tempfldr, "final") # Probably set this to a location where it can be permanently stored

  # Create temporary folders
  if(dir.exists(map.zips) == FALSE){
    dir.create(map.zips)
  }
  if(dir.exists(maps.fldr) == FALSE){
    dir.create(maps.fldr)
  }
  if(dir.exists(final.fldr) == FALSE){
    dir.create(final.fldr)
  }

  # Download each countries map file
  sapply(countries, function(x) download.file(paste0("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm2.8/shp/",x,"_adm_shp.zip"), file.path(map.zips,paste0(x,".zip"))))

  # Extract contents of zip files
  sapply(unlist(list.files(map.zips, full.names = TRUE)), unzip, exdir = maps.fldr)

  # Get list of shapefiles to be used
  shapefiles <- unlist(list.files(maps.fldr, pattern = "0.shp", full.names = TRUE))

  # Read all shapefiles
  shapefiles <- lapply(shapefiles, readOGR)

  # Combine all shapefiles into a single object
  final.map <- do.call(rbind, shapefiles)

  # Save the final combined map for later use
  writeOGR(obj = final.map, dsn = final.fldr, layer = "final.map", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

After the combined country map has been created. You can use this script to use the newly created map to check your dataset.

```
  # Dataframe with coordinates to check
  data_arvore <- data.frame(latitude = c(5.537175, 11.618371, rep(0,8)), 
                            longitude = c(-87.052112, -85.365203, rep(-99,8)))

  # Read in the map file created eariler
  map <- readOGR(file.path(final.fldr, "final.map.shp"))

  # Get points from dataframe on map
  pts <- SpatialPoints(data_arvore[,c("longitude","latitude")], proj4string=CRS(proj4string(map)))

  # Check which points are over ocean
  data_arvore$ocean <- is.na(over(pts, map)$FIPS)

  # Create a map for verification
  plot(map)
  points(pts, col = 3 - data_arvore$ocean, pch=16)

  # Remove points that are over ocean
  data_arvore <- data_arvore[data_arvore$ocean == FALSE, ]
```